# Is anyone aware of an open, relatively well supported framework to build telecoms applications on?

Tags: architecture, mobile, frameworks, telecommunication

Examples of such applications might be: SGSN, MME, the various IMS CSCF platforms, an MSC-Server, and SMS server, a SIP proxy etc.

Unlike the web services world which is awash with frameworks, it seems most telecoms kit is built on custom software architectures.

Note I am not looking for a discussion on the pros and cons of a particular framework - just a pointer to anything suitable...

Comment: Care to share the reason for the down vote, 4 years after the question was asked??

Answer (score 0):

It isn´t a complete answer, but these frameworks are widely used: SMS gateway: [Kannel](http://www.kannel.org/) and PBX and VoIp gateway: [Asterisk](http://www.asterisk.org/).

Comment: Thanks for the response - what I am really looking for is a framework for building applications like these - i.e. Asterisk uses their own dedicated architecture, rather than building on a common SIP or PBX framework